# Update username in navigation drawer when login with diffrent user in react native

Tags: react-native

I am showing username in drawernavigator, but when I logged out and logged in again with a different user, the username is not updating, it's showing old username.

I am also using didFocus Listener but it is also not working please help

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Image,Text, TouchableOpacity,MenuImage,navigation,AsyncStorage, Alert } from 'react-native';
import {widthPercentageToDP as wp, heightPercentageToDP as hp} from 'react-native-responsive-screen';
import {
createDrawerNavigator,
createStackNavigator,
DrawerItems,
} from 'react-navigation';
import WalkThrow from '../pages/WalkThrow';
import Login from '../pages/Login';
import Register from '../pages/Register';

class NavigationDrawerStructure extends Component {
static propTypes = {
    navigation: functionTypes.isRequired,
};
toggleDrawer = async() => {
    this.props.navigationProps.openDrawer();
};
render() {
    return (
    <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.toggleDrawer.bind(this)}>
        <Image
            source={require('../assets/images/menu48.png')}
            style={{ width: 25, height: 25, marginLeft: 15 }}
        />
        </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
    );
}
}

class NavigationImage extends Component {
toggleDrawer = async() => {
    this.props.navigationProps.openDrawer();
};
render() {
    return (
    <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.toggleDrawer. bind(this)}>
        <Image
            source={require('../assets/images/user.png')}
            style={{ width: 40, height: 40, marginRight:15 }}
        />
        </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
    );
}
}

class ShowUserName extends Component{
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
    getname:''
    }
} 

componentDidMount= async()=>{
    let getname = await AsyncStorage.getItem('userName');
    this.setState({getname:getname});
    const { navigation } = this.props;
    this.focusListener = navigation.addListener("didFocus", async() => {
    let getname = await AsyncStorage.getItem('userName');
    this.setState({getname:getname});
    });
}

render() {
    return (
    <View>
        <Text style={{color:'#fff',fontSize:23,padding:5}}>
        {this.state.getname}
        </Text>
    </View>
    );
}
}

const Logout= createStackNavigator({
Register:{
    screen:Register,
    navigationOptions:{
    header: null,
    },
},
Login: {
screen: Login,
navigationOptions:{
    header: null,
    }
},
ForgetPassword: {
    screen: ForgetPassword,
    navigationOptions:{
    header: null,
    }
},
initialRouteName: 'WalkThrow',
});



const Profile_StackNavigator = createStackNavigator({
Profile: {
    initialRouteName: 'Profile',
    screen:ChangeName,
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
    title: 'Profile',
    headerLeft: <NavigationDrawerStructure navigationProps={navigation} />,
    headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: '#3598db',
        shadowOpacity: 0, 
        elevation: 0,
    },
    headerTintColor: '#fff',
    }),
}
});

const ChangePassword_StackNavigator = createStackNavigator({
ChangePassword: {
    initialRouteName: 'WalkThrow',
    screen:ChangePassword,
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
    title: 'Change Password',
    headerLeft: <NavigationDrawerStructure navigationProps={navigation} />,
    headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: '#3598db',
        shadowOpacity: 0, 
        elevation: 0,
    },
    headerTintColor: '#fff',
    }),
},
});



const DashBoard_StackNavigator = createStackNavigator({
WalkThrow: {
    screen: WalkThrow,
    navigationOptions:{
    header: null,
},
}, 

const DrawerContent = (props) => (
<View>
    <View
    style={{
        backgroundColor: '#3598db',
        height: 200,
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
    }}>
    <Image
        source={require('../assets/images/user.png')}
        style={{ width:'36%', height: '50%' }}
    />
    <ShowUserName/>
    </View>
    <DrawerItems {...props} />
</View>
)

export default createDrawerNavigator({




ChangePassword: {
    screen: ChangePassword_StackNavigator,
    initialRouteName: 'Logout',
    navigationOptions: {
    drawerLabel: 'Change Password',
    drawerIcon: () => (
        <Image
        source={require('../assets/images/user48.png')}
        style={{width: 25, height: 25, }}
        />
    )
    },
},

Logout: {
    screen: Logout,
    initialRouteName: 'Logout',
    navigationOptions: {
    drawerLabel: 'Logout',
    drawerIcon: () => (
        <Image
        source={require('../assets/images/user48.png')}
        style={{width: 25, height: 25,}}
        />
    )
    },
},
},

{
contentComponent: DrawerContent,
});
```

I am showing username in drawernavigator,but when i logged out and login again with different user the username is not updating,its showing old username.when different user login then show the username for those user

Answer (score 0):

the issue is that this doesn't rerun because the drawer does not unmount

```
componentDidMount= async()=>{
    let getname = await AsyncStorage.getItem('userName');
    this.setState({getname:getname});
    const { navigation } = this.props;
    this.focusListener = navigation.addListener("didFocus", async() => {
    let getname = await AsyncStorage.getItem('userName');
    this.setState({getname:getname});
    });
}
```

the bigger problem with the architecture of your app is that you' using asyncStorage as your state management it isa huge anti pattern and will make your app really slow and battery draining in the long run.

you have to use some sort of state management ie Context API or redux, then you get your userName straight form the global state it will make the app much faster and solve your problem and probably many others you are experiencing

then your render will look something like this without any need to to set the state again in a lifeCycle Method, you may also need a default depending where you declared the drawer

```
render() {
    return (
    <View>
        <Text style={{color:'#fff',fontSize:23,padding:5}}>
        {this.props.SOMEGLOBALCONTEXTHERE.username || ''}
        </Text>
    </View>
    );
}
```